# Mariadb can not find system tables

Tags: mariadb-10.3

I am running mariadb 10.3.27 and after a erroneus long query maria db stoped working.

I restart it and check systemctl status.

Mariadb was working but also have the bellow errors:

```
[ERROR] mariadbd: Event Scheduler: An error occurred when initializing system tables. Disabling the Event Scheduler.
mariadbd[10942]: 2021-09-30 19:44:58 1 [Warning] Failed to load slave replication state from table mysql.gtid_slave_pos: 1146: Table 'mysql.gtid_slave_pos' doesn't exist
mariadbd[10942]: 2021-09-30 19:44:58 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
mariadbd[10942]: 2021-09-30 19:44:58 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
mariadbd[10942]: 2021-09-30 19:44:58 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mariadbd: ready for connections.
mariadbd[10942]: Version: '10.5.10-MariaDB'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MariaDB Server
systemd[1]: Started MariaDB 10.5.10 database server.
mariadbd[10942]: 2021-09-30 19:44:58 3 [ERROR] InnoDB: Table `mysql`.`innodb_table_stats` not found.
mariadbd[10942]: 2021-09-30 19:47:20 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 210930 19:47:20
mariadbd[10942]: 2021-10-01  6:29:22 14690 [ERROR] Column count of mysql.proc is wrong. Expected 21, found 20. Created with MariaDB 50565, now running 100510. Please use mariadb-upgrade to fix this error
```

Well I thnink this is very bad.  I can see that I am suggested to run mariadb-upgrade but I am afraid that this would break things. I also don't understand why I have suddenly to upgrade. It worked fine before the long running query.

Does anyone can help me with this?

Thank you i advance.

Answer (score 0):

Take a backup, then run `mariadb-upgrade`.

`mariadb-upgrade` **must** be run, one way or another, after upgrading. It is not optional, and you cannot expect MariaDB to work without this.

The fact that it *seemed to* work for a while does not make the above any less true.

On some Linux distros `mariadb-upgrade` is run automatically for you when you upgrade the MariaDB-server package, whereas on others it is not.